# Should I pull ethernet cable to my thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, ethernet

I'm going to be installing an ecobee3 smart thermostat, and need to pull some additional #18 thermostat wire.

Since I'm going to be pulling cable anyway, and I have a box of cat 5e ethernet cable, is there any reason not to pull that at the same time? Should I mount a junction box in the wall to tuck the unused ethernet cable into? Looks like the ecobee3 will require a slight mod to install over a junction box.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can connect the ecobee3 to an ethernet cable anyway...

Comment: @HariGanti yeah, this would mainly be for future-proofing

Comment: How many wires are going to be in the t-stat cable you're pulling?

Comment: @mmathis Do you mean for future thermostats or other things? If not for the thermostat, then your question is basically, "Should I pull some Cat cable through my walls along with the t-stat wires?" In that case, sure.

Comment: @HariGanti both? That's my question, sounds like it definitely won't hurt. Going to pull 18/8 t-stat cable.

Comment: Well, I doubt any future smart thermostat isn't going to have Wi-Fi, so unless you plan to install a wall plate with an RJ-45 receptacle, I don't see any value. That said, you certainly could.